# How do you find the pitch of an Audio Clip at a certain time in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, microphone, pitch

I am creating a program that requires me to retrieve the pitch of the current microphone input, which is being recorded in an Audio Clip. I have tried using functions such as AudioClip.GetSpectrumData, AudioSource.GetOutputData, and AudioClip.GetData to obtain the pitch, but they only return the sound's amplitude. How can I obtain the pitch of the current microphone input?

Comment: This discussion regarding the spectrum data should help.  [Get the frequency from an AudioSource](https://discussions.unity.com/t/get-the-frequency-from-an-audiosource/172418)